# jp.archive.ubuntu.com is not updated

Tags: apt, updates, mirrors

I set "http://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/" as a mirror site in /etc/apt/sources.list.

I failed to update php7.4 packages to apply a security fixes (CVE-2022-31625 and CVE-2022-31626),
because the jp.archive repository doesn't have the fixed latest packages.

The index file on the repository is old, as below, seems not to be updated.

- 2022-06-16 09:02  http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ls-lR.gz
- 2022-06-01 00:38  http://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ls-lR.gz

Will it be updated, or the repository is obsolete?

Comment: This will depend greatly on which version of Ubuntu you're running. Could you [edit]  your question to state whether you're using 20.04 or another release?

Comment: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors shows UNIVERSITY OF TOYAMA with Ubuntu Japanese LoCo *Up to date* for as I see it; so I'd check you've updated your sources, and if unhappy, maybe select another mirror on https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors